# How to debug this plsql code?

Tags: oracle, plsql, syntax-error

I am getting error while executing ps-sql procedure.

below is my script.

```
set serveroutput on size 100000
set echo off
set feedback off
set lines 300

declare

  cursor sessinfo is
    SELECT NVL(s.username, '(oracle)') AS      username,
           s.osuser,
           s.sid,
           s.serial#,
           p.spid,
           s.status,
           s.module,
           s.machine,
           s.program,
           TO_CHAR(s.logon_Time,'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AS logon_time,
           s.last_call_et/3600  last_call_et_Hrs,
           lpad(t.sql_text,30) "Last SQL"
      from gv$session s, 
           gv$sqlarea t,
           gv$process p 
      where s.sql_address = t.address and 
            s.sql_hash_value =t.hash_value and 
            p.addr=s.paddr and 
            s.status='INACTIVE' and 
            s.last_call_et > (3600) 
      order by last_call_et;

  sess sessinfo%rowtype;
  sql_string1 Varchar2(2000);
  sql_string2 Varchar2(2000);
begin
  open sessinfo;

  loop
    fetch sessinfo into sess;
    exit when sessinfo%notfound;

    sql_string1 := 'sid='       || sess.sid     ||
                   ' serail#='  || sess.serial# ||
                   ' machine='  || sess.machine ||
                   '      program=' || sess.program ||
                   ' username=' || sess.username ||
                   ' Inactive_sec=' || sess.last_call_et ||
                   '    OS_USER=' || sess.osuser;

    sql_string2 := 'alter system kill session ' || chr(39) ||
                   sess.sid || ',' || chr(39) || sess.serial# || ';';


    dbms_output.put_line(sql_string1);
    dbms_output.put_line(sql_string2);
  end loop;

  close sessinfo;
end;
/
quit;
```

i am getting below error. please help me.

```
[oracle@localhost ~]$ sqlplus -s '/as sysdba' @inactive12.sql
sql_string1:='sid='||sess.sid||' serail#='||sess.serial#||' machine='||sess.machine||' program='||sess.program||' username='||sess.username||' Inactive_sec='||sess.last_call_et||' OS_USER='||sess.osuser;
                                                                                                                                                                    *
ERROR at line 12:
ORA-06550: line 12, column 165:
PLS-00302: component 'LAST_CALL_ET' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 12, column 1:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

Comment: What do you want to use: `last_call_et` (seconds) or `last_call_et_Hrs` (hours)?

Answer (score 5):

You aliased `last_call_et` as `last_call_et_hrs`, so the cursor doesn't see `last_call_et` anymore, use the aliased column `last_call_et_hrs`.

Comment: Or add `last_call_et` to the select list, in addition to the computed `last_call_et_hrs`.